The term 'Get-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration' is not recognized as the name of a > cmdlet
I'm using Exchange 2019 (on-premise), I want to run this cmdlet to view the junklist of a user:

Get-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration -Identity "user mailbox"

but here is the output:

Get-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration : The term 'Get-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

Get-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration

  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException




I searched a lot but I didn't find anyhing related. what is wrong?

Make sure you launch the Exchange Management Shell if using Exchange on-prem, otherwise call Connect-ExchangeOnline before doing anything else

Additionally if you are in the Exchange Management Shell and receiving the error, make sure you have the appropriate permissions in Exchange. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/find-exchange-cmdlet-permissions?view=exchange-ps
